# Share an ipa distribution file?

Tags: iphone, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to create my distribution build as an .ipa. It's possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag your .app into iTunes, then right click to it and "Show in Finder".
In XCode 4, you can also use Build and Archive.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Just an small doubt before accepting your answer: The .ipa file generated with the build and archive option includes the mobile provision inside ?, or i need to provide the .ipa and the provision ?

Comment: You'll need to provide both the .ipa and the provision file.

Answer (score 1):

Use testflight.com You just drag the ipa file into it, and then it e-mails it to your beta testers. super easy.